# I fail to run caret's nnet regression

Tags: r, neural-network

I tried to run regression using caret's nnet, but I got a error.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
feature = rnorm(100, 0, 1) %>% as.matrix() 
colnames(feature) = "x1"
outcome = rnorm(100, 0, 1) %>% as.matrix()
colnames(feature) = "y1"
model = caret::train(
  x = feature, y = outcome, method = "nnet",
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(size=c(1:3), decay=seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)),
  weights = NULL, linout = TRUE
  )
```

`Error: Metric RMSE not applicable for classification models`

Of course, I want to regress, not classify. In order to show this, I set the option `linout = TRUE`. What went wrong?

Also, I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440974/unable-to-run-parameter-tuning-for-xgboost-regression-model-using-caret), and tried to remove as.matrix, but it also shows other error.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
feature = rnorm(100, 0, 1) %>% as.double()
outcome = rnorm(100, 0, 1) %>% as.double()
CATE_model = caret::train(
  x = feature, y = outcome, method = "nnet",
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(size=c(1:3), decay=seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)),
  weights = NULL, linout = TRUE
  )
```

`Error: Please use column names for 'x'`

Thanks, a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input of the Neural Network seems to require colnames.
This makes sense as the trained neural net might later need to identify the correct columns in its input for prediction.

if you force your features into a Dataframe with colnames (in my case `x`), it works.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
feature = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 0, 1) %>% as.double()) # changed line 
outcome = rnorm(100, 0, 1) %>% as.double()
CATE_model = caret::train(
  x = feature, y = outcome, method = "nnet",
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(size=c(1:3), decay=seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)),
  weights = NULL, linout = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot. The code I first showed tried to set colnames of feature like below.
```
feature = rnorm(100, 0, 1) %>% as.matrix() 
colnames(feature) = "x1"

```
I think nnet works with matrix also. Should I use data.frame instead of matrix?

Comment: I think you could use either. I think the problem was that the outcome was defined as a matrix in the your first piece of code. Only the Income needs column names it seems.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to following your advice, it worked well!