# Using rpy2 w/ caret attempts classification instead of regression

Tags: python, r, r-caret, rpy2, glmnet

I have data that I have created and preprocessed in Python that I would like to import to R and perform a  k-fold cross-validated LASSO fit using `glmnet`. I want control over which observations are used in each fold, so I want to use `caret` to do this.

However, I have found that `caret` interprets my data as a classification instead of a regression problem, and promptly fails. Here is what I hope is a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

pandas2ri.activate()
numpy2ri.activate()

# Import essential R packages
glmnet = importr('glmnet')
caret = importr('caret')
base = importr('base')

# Define X and y input 
dummy_x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000, 5), columns=('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
dummy_y = np.random.rand(10000)

# Convert pandas DataFrame to R data.frame
with localconverter(robjects.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter): 
 dummy_x_R = robjects.conversion.py2rpy(dummy_x) 

# Use caret to perform the fit using default settings 
caret_test = caret.train(**{'x': dummy_x_R, 'y': dummy_y, 'method': 'glmnet'})
```

rpy2 fails, giving this cryptic error message from R:

```
RRuntimeError: Error: Metric RMSE not applicable for classification models
```

What could be causing this? According to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762536/r-xgboost-on-caret-attempts-to-perform-classification-instead-of-regression), it may be the case that caret is assuming that at least one of my variables is an integer type, and so defaults to thinking this is a classification instead of a regression problem.

However, I have checked both X and y using `typeof`, and they are clearly doubles:

```
base.sapply(dummy_x_R, 'typeof')                                                                                                                                                     
>>> array(['double', 'double', 'double', 'double', 'double'], dtype='<U6')

base.sapply(dummy_y, 'typeof')                                                                                                                                                       
>>> array(['double', 'double', 'double', ..., 'double', 'double', 'double'],
      dtype='<U6')
```

Why am I getting this error? All the default settings to `train` assume a regression model, so why does `caret` assume a classification model when used in this way?

Comment: Since you are generating random data, can you successfully run a similar exercise and call `caret` only in R? Also, why not simply call `train` with named args: `caret.train(x=dummy_x_R, y=dummy_y, method='glmnet')`?

Comment: @Parfait: I didn't realise that rpy2 was that flexible. The documentation wasn't clear to me as to what could be named at what required kwargs. 

Anyway, I tried what you suggested in R and found that train ran without any error: 

```x <- data.frame(replicate(5, runif(10000)))``` , ```y <- runif(10000)```, ```caret_test <- caret::train(x = x, y = y, method = 'glmnet')```

Whatever the issue is, it seems to be with how ```rpy2``` is passing my data into ```caret```. Any ideas as to how to debug this further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In situations like this, the first step is to identify whether the unexpected outcome originated from the Python or rpy2 side, or the R side.

The conversion from pandas to R, or numpy to R appears to work as expected, as least for array types:

```
>>> [x.typeof for x in dummy_x_R]                                                         
[<RTYPES.REALSXP: 14>,
 <RTYPES.REALSXP: 14>,
 <RTYPES.REALSXP: 14>,
 <RTYPES.REALSXP: 14>,
 <RTYPES.REALSXP: 14>]
```

I am guessing that this is what you might have done for `dummy_y`.

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri                                               
>>> with localconverter(robjects.default_converter + numpy2ri.converter):  
        dummy_y_R = robjects.conversion.py2rpy(dummy_y)
>>> dummy_y_R.typeof                                                                 
<RTYPES.REALSXP: 14>
```

However, a rather subtle conversion detail is at root of the issue. `dummy_y_R` has a "shape" (attribute `dim` in R), while `caret` expects a shape-less R array (a "vector" in R lingo) in order to perform a regression. One can force `dummy_y` to be an R vector with:

```
caret_test = caret.train(**{'x': dummy_x_R,
                            'y': robjects.FloatVector(dummy_y),
                            'method': 'glmnet'})
```

Answer (score 0):

To use R methods, be sure all inputs are R objects. Therefore, consider converting the `dummy_y` numpy array to an R vector which you can do with `base.as_double`:

```
...
dummy_y_R = base.as_double(dummy_y)

caret.train(x=dummy_x_R, y=dummy_y_R, method='glmnet')
```